# C# Give access to specific unrelated class

Tags: c#, properties, xna, access-modifiers

Is there a way to modify the access of some attribute to a specific class? More specifically, I want to create a property that has a public get, but can only be set by a certain class.

Example:

```
public Class1
{
    Class2.SomeInt = 5;
}

public static Class2
{
    private static int someInt;
    public static int SomeInt
    {
        get { return someInt; }
        (give access to Class1 only somehow?) set { someInt = value; }
    }
}
```

Update (more info):
I'm doing this in xna, I want the main type (Game1) to be the only thing that can modify a static helper class. It's for a group project in school, we're using SVN (not sure how that'd be relevant), I could just tell everyone in my group to avoid setting the values, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Comment: You'd have to nest one class in another to make it work.

Comment: If I nest Class2 in Class1, how should I access it from other classes? Would I need an instance of Class1 or need to say Class1.Class2.SomeInt?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? There's probably an easier way to get what you need.

Comment: How about not setting property from that class? Why do you want to prevent it? Who is the consumer of your class, you or someone else?

Comment: Atleast which your example code, does anything stop you from declaring `static int SomeInt {get; private set;}` inside `Class1`?

Comment: Hm, you could declare that `static int` in `Game1` directly, with a private setter. Every `GameComponent` need a reference to `Game1` anyway, so you could access it by `Game.SomeInt`, and would not be able to modify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like the `friend` access modifier, which C# doesn't have.  The closest I've seen to this in C# is to have the "unrelated" class be an interface and have a private implementation within a class.  Something like this:

```
public interface IWidget
{
    void DoSomethingPublic();
}

public class SomeObject
{
    private ObjectWidget _myWidget = new ObjectWidget();
    public IWidget MyWidget
    {
        get { return _myWidget; }
    }

    private class ObjectWidget
    {
        public void DoSomethingPublic()
        {
            // implement the interface
        }

        public void DoSomethingPrivate()
        {
            // this method can only be called from within SomeObject
        }
    }
}
```

Code external to `SomeObject` can interact with `MyWidget` and sees anything that's on the `IWidget` interface, but code internal to `SomeObject` can also non-interface public members on `MyWidget`.

Comment: Knowing that what I'm looking for is a 'friend' access modifier I did a bit of research and found
 [StrongNameIdentityPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermission.aspx)
. I'm still reading about it to see if I can use it but if that works I'll check this answer off as the one I used

Comment: @user3390855: You might also look into the `InternalsVisibleTo` directive for assemblies.  It could easily lead to a couple of assemblies being more tightly-coupled than otherwise necessary, but might do the trick in some scenarios allowing you to use `internal` as kind of a replacement for `friend`.

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing. I was going to change the link but ran out of time to edit the comment. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be impossible in C#. You can only use `public`, `protected`, `protected internal`, `internal` and `private` access modifiers.
But you can, for instance, make an assembly that contains only these two classes and set the `internal` modifier for the `SomeInt` setter or nest one class into another.
If you want to just hide a setter from the IntelliSense, you can define this setter in some interface and implement it explicitly:

```
public interface IHidden<T>
{
    T HiddenPropery { set; }
}

public class SomeClass : IHidden<int>
{
    private int someInt;
    public int HiddenPropery
    {
        get { return someInt; }
    }

    int IHidden<int>.HiddenPropery
    {
        set { someInt = value; }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// This works:
((IHidden<int>)new SomeClass()).HiddenPropery = 1;
// This doesn't:
new SomeClass().HiddenPropery = 1;
```